# Initialize a uInt128 value from a string

Tags: c

I how can i initialize a uint128 value from a string in C if there is no native uint128?

is this correct? if not how

```
struct uint128 {
    
    uint64_t left;
    uint64_t right;
};

void initializeUint128(const char *input, struct uint128 *output) {

    output->right = strtoull(input+16, NULL, 16);

    char *tmp = alloca(17);
    memcpy(tmp, input, 16);

    tmp[16] = '\0';
    output->left = strtoull(tmp, NULL, 16);
}
```

Comment: If you know your input comrpises the full 32 digits, your code looks fine. Did you try it? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @CarlNorum So that is fine doing such to turn string number into uint128 value? - can you show me good way to have different digit lenght instead of fixed?

Comment: @CarlNorum are you sure that works? I don't think that works. 000000000000000010000000000000001 is not 2^64+1

Comment: Could give us info on your C compiler ? (C has 128bits integer support since C99)

Comment: @user253751 why not?

Comment: Alternate to `char *tmp = alloca(17);` --> `char tmp[17];`

Comment: @CarlNorum because 2^64+1 is 1.8446744e+19 and while Google didn't tell me *all* the digits, the digits  844674 definitely do not appear in the number 000000000000000010000000000000001

Comment: You see it's converting as hex, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i initialize a uint128 value from a string in C if there is no native uint128?

First implement arithmetics of uint128 numbers. Implement addition and multiplication.

Then do a conversion like with any other datatype. Read one digit from the string, multiply number by 10, add it to number. Sample interface might look like this:

```
struct uint128 uint128_initialize_from_string_in_base10(const char *p, const char **endptr) {
     struct uint128 temp;
     uint128_initialize_zero(&temp);
     while (*p && isdigit(*p)) {
         char digit = *p++ - '0'; // or whatever base you want to have
         uint128_multiply_int(&temp, 10);
         uint128_add_int(&temp, digit);
     }
     if (endptr) *endptr = p;
     return temp;
}
```

> is this correct?

It's syntactically correct. It's missing `#include <stdint.h>`.

> if not how

Passing a string with length less then `16` is undefined

The code does not check for conversion errors.

The code assumes the input string is in base 16.

> can you show me good way to have different digit lenght instead of fixed?

Use the second argument of `strtoll` to detect where the conversion has ended. I could see:

```
struct uint128 uint128_initialize_from_string_with_two_numbers_separated_by_whitespaces(
           const char *input) {
    const char *endptr;
    struct uint128 output;

    unsigned long long tempull = strtoull(input, &endptr, 0);
    // handle error
    output.left = tempull;

    tempull = strtoull(endptr, NULL, 0);
    // handle error
    output.right = tempull;

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Candidate simplification `while (*p && isdigit(*p)) {` --> `while (isdigit(*p)) {`

Comment: Perfect! thank you - your first code was a good guide to me

Answer (score 0):

First:

You're using a dynamic allocation for the tmp buffer in the `initializeUint128` and it should be freed after the left member assignation. A better way here is to use a buffer on the stack with `char tmp[17];` as suggested by @chux - Reinstate Monica.

Second:

As you're using fixed type integers `uint64_t` from [C99](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/c/c99), i guess your C compiler is C99 compliant.

Since [C99](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/c/c99), there's a generic support for 128bits integer through `__int128` and `unsigned __int128`, even if the target CPU doesn't have native 128bits integer support.

**Beware** that this support does not extend to the standard C library. As an exemple, `printf("%032X\n", (unsigned __int128)bigint);` will only print the LSB (or MSB, depending on the Endianness of your target system) part of bigint. Thus you have to care about the *Endianness* in your case if you want to decompose the bigint, as for the case of the 0x000000000000001A0000000000102243 value below.

To this day, most C compiler can't compute a 128bits value directly (like `unsigned __int128 value = 0x1A0000000000102244;`) as there is not literal for it in the actual standard,  you'll get a warning / error at compile time. But, for the 128bits initialization, note in the code below how this value is computed for the `second_value` variable. It could be a more appropriate way in your case than a string initialization.

To make it more clear, an example with your code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
struct uint128 {

    uint64_t left;
    uint64_t right;
};

union uint128u { struct uint128 source; unsigned __int128 big; };

typedef union uint128u uint128_t;

void initializeUint128(const char *input, struct uint128 *output) {

    output->right = strtoull(input+16, NULL, 16);

    char tmp[17]; // char *tmp = alloca(17); see above why stack is more adequate here
    memcpy(tmp, input, 16);

    tmp[16] = '\0';
    output->left = strtoull(tmp, NULL, 16);
}
int main(int nbargs, char *args[]) {

   // Initialization through string in your structure uint128
   struct uint128 value;
   initializeUint128("000000000000001A0000000000102241", &value);
   printf("L:%016X R:%016X\n", value.left, value.right);

   // Initialization through string on your structure uint128 mirrored with __int128
   uint128_t bigvalue;
   initializeUint128("000000000000001A0000000000102242", &bigvalue.source);
   printf("L:%016X R:%016X\n", bigvalue.source.left, bigvalue.source.right);
   printf("The (wrong) whole with no int size specifier : %032X\n", bigvalue.big);
   printf("The (wrong) whole with ll : %032llX\n", bigvalue.big);

   // Initialization through shift uint64 + uint64 of __int128
   unsigned __int128 second_value = 0x1A;
   second_value = second_value<<64;
   second_value+=0x102243;
   uint128_t big2;
   big2.big=second_value;
   printf("L:%016X R:%016X\n", big2.source.left, big2.source.right);
   printf("The (wrong) whole second value : %032llX\n", second_value);
}
```

will print on a x86_64 (Little_Endian) :

```
L:000000000000001A R:0000000000102241
L:000000000000001A R:0000000000102242
The (wrong) whole with no int size specifier : 0000000000000000000000000000001A
The (wrong) whole with ll : 0000000000000000000000000000001A
L:0000000000102243 R:000000000000001A
The (wrong) whole second value : 00000000000000000000000000102243
```

Answer (score 0):

> Initialize a uInt128 value from a (hexadecimal) string

Find the string's length and convert the right-most 16 characters into `output->right` and leading ones, if any, into `output->left`.

```
void initializeUint128(const char *input, struct uint128 *output) {
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    if (len > 16) {
      if (sscanf(input, "%*" SCNx64 "%16" SCNx64, 
          (int) len - 16,  &output->left, &output->right) != 2) {
        Handle_Failure();
      }
    } else {
      output->left = 0;
      if (sscanf(input, "%" SCNx64, &output->right) != 1) {
        Handle_Failure();
      }
    }
 }
```

This approach does get fooled with in-between spaces.